# Vue component not rendering in basic php

Tags: php, vue.js, vue-component

I am using basic php and trying to render vue component in html. But it always show blank page. I am not getting any js error.

Am I missing anything in below code?

My Directory Structure is like below.

[Directory Structure. I am sorry, unable to show image due to less rep points.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YK0uG.png)

**app.js is in public folder. Below is the code**

```
Vue.component("login", ("loginComponent.vue"));
var app = new Vue({
    el: "app",
    data: {

    },
    mounted: function() {
        console.log("Mounted");
    },
    methods: {

    }
});
```

**Component Code present in loginComponent.vue file**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <form role="form" class="row">
            <label for="Email Address" class="control-label">UserName</label>
            <input type="text" name="Email Address" class="form-control">

            <label for="Password" class="control-label">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="Password" class="form-control">

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" >
                Login
            </button>
        </form>
    </div>
</template>
```

**loginView.php file code is like below.**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Login</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>        
        <script src="./public/js/app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app"> 
            <login></login>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `loginComponent.vue` or `login.vue` ?

Comment: I am sorry, Let me explain the directory structure. There are total 3 files.
1. loginComponent.vue 2. loginView.php and app.js

Comment: I read that. You are registering `Vue.component("login", ("./components/Auth/login.vue"));` in your first code, in your second you talk about `loginComponent.vue`?!

Comment: I am sorry, By mistake, I typed the wrong path. I have corrected the path now.

Comment: You shouldn't type code, but _paste_ your exisiting one. Anyway, since your `app.js` is located in `public/js` and your component is located in root, have you tried `Vue.component("login", ("../../loginComponent.vue"));`?

Comment: Can you register single file components like that? Not saying it's wrong, genuinely curious, as I haven't seen it before and it looks a little strange to me - especially wrapped in parentheses - and I cannot find it documented.

Comment: I tried above code, still not rendering. Can u please check the above 3 files your side, if they are rendering?

Comment: Are you missing `require('path/to/component.vue')`?

Comment: @DarraghEnright : I tried by adding require: I got error in js: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Comment: If `require` is not available I guess you are not using a build system and are using vue with a `<script>` file instead. Disregard my last question in that case. I'm still curious to see a single file component registered in that way however, have you used that successfully in other parts of your code?

Comment: You need `webpack` to parse `.vue` files.

Answer (score 3):

On your 3rd line in app.js, `"app"` is not a valid selector, try `"#app"` instead.

**Edit**:
There are 3 things to fix.

1. You are not loading loginComponent.vue
   `loginComponent.vue` is not loaded on your browser. You need to add a script tag in `loginView.php`.

   ```
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
   <script src="loginComponent.vue"></script>
   <script src="app.js"></script>
   ```
2. You can't use .vue syntax without webpack. Your `loginComponent.vue` 
   are ran as a javascript, which means `<template>` tag is not available and you have to set template as a string.

   ```
   var loginComponent = { 
   template: `
     <div>
       <form role="form" class="row">
         <label for="Email Address" class="control-label">UserName Or EmailAddress</label>
         <input type="text" name="Email Address" class="form-control">

         <label for="Password" class="control-label">Password</label>
         <input type="password" name="Password" class="form-control">

         <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" >
           Login
         </button>
       </form>
     </div>
   `,
   ```
3. You have to wait DOMContentLoaded before mounting the app.
   In app.js,

   ```
   Vue.component("login", loginComponent);
   document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
       var app = new Vue({
           el: "#app",
           data: {},
           mounted: function () {
               console.log("Mounted");
           },
           methods: {}
       });
   })
   ```

Comment: I am sorry, It is still not rendering the html from component.

Comment: Can u please try the above files in question your side? if that is working your side?

Comment: Are the any errors or warnings on your console? When I tried I got `[Vue warn]: Invalid Component definition: loginComponent.vue`

Comment: I got an error after applying the code above: Here is the screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxT1R.png

Comment: Oh sorry I misunderstood your setup. You can't use single file component (.vue files) without building tool like webpack.

Comment: To do so, you need to introduce webpack, a module build system of javascript. because vue files need to be built into js files so browsers can understand. Here is the document about single file component.
https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html#For-Users-New-to-Module-Build-Systems-in-JavaScript
And this document explains webpack configuration step by step.
https://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/

Hope it helps.